# Rare error in MySQL syntax using java eclipse

Tags: mysql, jdbc

'query' accumulates queries, and one is INSERT INTO root:

```
public StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer("");
private String tmp="";

tmp="INSERT INTO `root` (`root_`) VALUES ('";
tmp=tmp.concat(root);
tmp=tmp.concat("');");
query.append(tmp);

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query.toString());
ps.executeUpdate();
query.delete(0, query.length());
```

The first time I did this was normally compiled.

System.out.println(query); show this:

```
INSERT INTO `root` (`root_`) VALUES ('value1');
```

But the second time 'query' contains:

```
 INSERT INTO `rel_root_doc` (`freq`,`id_doc`, `id_root`) VALUES (1,1,1);
 INSERT INTO `root` (`root_`) VALUES ('value2');
```

and I'm having this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near .

```
'INSERT INTO `root` (`root_`) VALUES ('value2')' at line 2
```

But if I copy and paste the same code in MySQLWorkbench, it works perfect.

Thanks for read.

Comment: If you use a PreparedStatement, then please use it correctly to guard you against SQL injection. Do not concatenate values into the query text, use the `?` parameter placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Statement` may only contain one SQL query. You will need one `Statement` (or `PreparedStatement`) per query.

Comment: is there any way to make multiple queries, so as I'm trying?
thanks for the answer :)

Comment: AFIK there is no way to execute several queries in one `Statement`. But it also looks like you do not need a `PreparedStatement` at all. You could just directly run the Statements like this: `Statement s = con.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable multiple queries with the MySQL JDBC driver with a [configuration property](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) called `allowMultiQueries`.

However, I would not recommend to enable this option, because it weakens security.  You create more opportunities for hackers to perpetrate SQL injection attacks.

And I have a recollection that multi-queries don't work with prepared statements anyway (but I haven't tested this to be certain).